# HTML rendering of tags in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following text in the model object, `<b>Hello<b>` which i need to display as **Hello**
But I get the following output `<b>Hello<b>` instead of **Hello**

I did the following in the .cshtml file

```
<td>@WebUtility.HtmlDecode(lookup.LookupTextDesc)</td>
```

What needs to be done so as to get the html rendered output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw(your object value)` to render as html inside view. Btw `<b>Hello<b>` should be `<b>Hello</b>` if it's html.